# I intend to exempt 0 as a valid value in a positive integer field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

`class Sales(models.Model): customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL) quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0) goods_Pending = models.BooleanField()`

1. I would like to exempt 0 as a valid response in the Positive Integer Field

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, [Validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators) should be work,
as per documentation

```
def exempt_zero(value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            ('Please enter a value greater than 0'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

class sales(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, validators=[exempt_zero])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Beware, you have a small typo in your class definition (`clas` instead of `class`). Thank you for your answer and happy coding :)

Comment: @Antoine My bad, thanks for letting me know!